# Don't escape bibtex citation in pandoc conversion

Tags: ms-word, pandoc, bibtex

I am having to work with word users who don't use bibtex. However I am trying to create a workflow where those users simply input [@citation] directly in the word doc. Then I use `pandoc` to convert that word doc back to markdown so I can more readily use bibtex. So here is what is in the word doc (`foo.docx`):

```
Sentence with a citation [@foo]
```

Then I run this pandoc code:

```
pandoc -s foo.docx -t markdown -o foo.md
```

Then resulting markdown is:

```
Sentence with a citation \[\@foo\]
```

Because of these escaped characters, I can't actually generate the citations. Happy to entertain other ideas to make this work but merging markdown and office users seems to be always a bit friction-y. The ultimately question is how to maintain citation from word to markdown?